# Changing a part of my output code to alphanumerics in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, alphanumeric

I have a script that which combines a random string with a time stamp -

```
def randomStringDigits(stringLength=6):
    """Generate a random string of letters and digits """
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))

letters = string.ascii_uppercase

import datetime
# Current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
datestr = now.strftime("%m%d%H%M%Y")

rdmCode = randomStringDigits(6) + datestr
```

I would like to change the month and hour to their alphanumeric partner aka 01=a, 02=b etc.

Preferably I would like the month to be in uppercase and the hour in lowercase. For example, this code would print - dtwk0T040713492020 and I would like it to be dtwk0T**D**07**m**492020

I'm pretty new to coding so not sure where I should start, should I be splitting the string into an array?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dictionary, pairing the month number to a letter:

```
mdict={1:'A',2:'B'}
```

you simply add the letters in between:

```
datestr = now.strftime(mdict[now.month]+"%mm%d%H%M%Y")
```

Note: if the number <--> letter relation is alphabetical order you can use:

```
chr(ord('@')+number) #Capital letters
chr(ord('`')+number) #lower case letters
```

i.e., you could use something like this:

```
datestr = now.strftime(chr(ord('@')+now.month)+"%d"+chr(ord('`')+now.hour)+"%M%Y")
```

Comment: That would require me to change the script each time. Is there not a way of replacing it automatically within the script? So that way if I ran the module next month it would show E instead of D.